# Calculate the sum of all even numbers from 1 to a with while loop

Tags: javascript

I've commented my code and can't understand what is wrong:

```html
function testWhile(a) {
    var x = 1;             // we count from 1
    var sum = 0;           // first, sum equals 0
    while (x <= a) {       // we have a condition from 1 to a
        x++;               // we add 1 because we move ahead
        if (x % 2 === 0) { // we check whether it is even
            sum = x + sum; // we refresh the sum

        }
    }

    return sum; 
}           // we return sum
```

Comment: Your code seems to be okay, except for he missing `}` at the end.

Comment: I think `x++;` would come at the bottom of while loop

Comment: This code is giving right answer. may be typo mistake but you missed last braces "}" after return statement.

Comment: the screen says Failed test #1. Wrong answer
Input:
3

Your output:
6
Correct output:
2

Comment: @Dean You are correct, I removed my comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although the better way suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51874377/1081909) but problem with your code is  `x++` condition  that is before `modulas` operation causing the extra addition of **last even number**.

By moving **x++** in the end of **while loop** will work with your code:

```js
function testWhile(a) {
    var x=1;// we count from 1
    var sum=0;// first, sum equals 0
    while (x<=a){ //we have a condition from 1 to a
       
        if (x % 2 === 0) {//we check whether it is even
    sum=x+sum;//we refresh the sum
           
        }
         x++; //we add 1 because we move ahead
    }
    
    return sum;//we return sum
    }
    console.log(2==testWhile(3));
    console.log(12==testWhile(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Cerbrus said, your code is missing `}`. But, there is a better way to solve your problem. Just using the sum formula.

```
function testWhile(a) {
    if (a % 2 == 1)
        return (2 + (a - 1)) / 2 * ((a - 1) / 2);
    return (2 + a) / 2 * (a / 2);
}
```

Comment: The 2nd line can be simplified to: `((2 + a) * a) / 4`. That first `return` statement can be replaced with `a--;`